# React : Reverse function is not working in mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on page where I am showing data that are coming from API . Actually I am trying to display array data in reverse order but it not displaying data in reverse. when I refresh a page , first time data is displaying in reverse but after 3 seconds data is revert and display in original form . please help me thanks

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DayPicker from "react-day-picker";
import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";
import "./style.css";
import axios from "axios";

class DiarySideBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("/api/diary/all").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data.rows
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="calendarWrapper">
          <DayPicker />
        </div>
        <div className="activeTaskMainWrapper">
          <h6 className="activeTaskHeaderWrapper">Active Tasks</h6>
          {data
            .reverse()
            .slice(0, 5)
            .map(newData => (
              <div className="activeTaskText">
                <b>{newData.taskType}</b>
                <p>{newData.subject}</p>
                <hr />
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DiarySideBar;
```

Comment: What are you doing after the three seconds? Ie what causes the re-render?

Comment: I mean to say after some seconds array is render in original form I want to render array in reverse order

Comment: First of all use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` and next what if the reversing logic is done in `componentDidMount` or separate function instead of `render` function. This way it would not re-render and go back to original order.

Comment: please answer in question, I want to vote your question

Comment: Is this the only thing you changed in your component? Has there been already `componentDidMount` in your component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`

Try reversing logic in `componentDidMount` or a separate function instead of `render` function.

This way it would not re-render and go back to original order as you require.

Comment: `reverse` in render should not trigger a rerender. Am I missing something?

Comment: The point was to put the logic in `componentDidMount` so that the reversing logic only runs whilst component mount and not with every re-render.

Comment: Yes, `componentDidMount` is the suggested method but this also works with `componentWillMount`. This can't be the problem. There must be something else causing a rerender. Using `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount `can't solve this.

Comment: I am not sure of the exact issue may be some parent component is causing re-render, that is why I suggested to move reversing logic out of render method which clearly worked for OP. If mutating was issue, he should never get correct results i suppose.

Comment: I get your point, moving the `reverse` out of render solves the problem but it also hides the "real" rerendering problem I guess. Something is fishy there :)

Answer (score 13):

The [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function mutates the original array - that is your state variable and that can lead to the unexpected results.
Please clone the array before the reversal with the [array spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...data].reverse()` or a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) call `data.slice().reverse()`.

Edit: Since 2023 you can also use [`toReversed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed) method to perform the reverse without affecting the original array. It makes a copy as a result instead of mutating the source.

Comment: Here is the reason. I missed the "in place" change for the `reverse` method. Good catch. This the actual problem and this is the right answer.

Comment: Though, as a second thought, mutating the state is a problem but this does not cause a rerender I guess. Still, I'm not sure what is the OP's real problem here.

Comment: It should be assumed that a `render` function can be called many times, even when not directly called (for example, after some parent component is updated). No matter when and no matter how it is called - it should return a result purely based on the props and the state. That makes it a pure function `f(x)` that has no unintended side-effects.

Comment: Ok, I get this but this can't be the real problem here, right? This does not cause a rerender.

Comment: Other components may cause this component to re-render, for example, parent components calling `setState` after some data been fetched asynchronously. The state variable will go like [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3], ... etc. leading to a random state based on how many times it has been rendered. You must assume that components re-render themselves and it should never lead to a broken state.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the point that OP is using `reverse` before `slice`. Yes, a rerender causes the order of state here. Good point!